# AWS: Your system is not supported by certbot-auto anymore and Amazon EC2 Linux SSL certbot-auto

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I want to Configure SSL / TLS on Amazon Linux "Using Let's Encrypt with Certbot on Amazon Linux ami / 2018.03-release-notes" as described in the document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-ami.htmlthe document but but
when I run the `sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel`

I have some kind of strange message[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4imsA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CZEE.png)

I don't know what to do anymore, I failed everywhere without success, I don't know if that's the problem.

I have already successfully configured SSL / TLS on Amazon Linux "Using Let's Encrypt with Certbot on Amazon Linux ami / 2018.03-release-notes" as described in the document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr /AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-ami.htmldescribed in the document this way and I never got this message.

After I try to install certbot as described on the amazon document I have this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhH3R.png)

Please help me.

Comment: `certbot-auto` is no longer supported and you should use your OS's packages for certbot.

Comment: @bk2204 How do I do this please, I'm not too familiar with server and aws.  Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with Amazon Linux since I don't use AWS.  If you aren't either, I'd suggest using a more common distro like Debian or Ubuntu, which will have the `certbot` package available.